# Disable start menu when pressing the WIN key

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, start-menu, remapping, windows-key

I would like the start menu to not open when pressing the windows key on the keyboard. In my case I have a different program ([Wox](http://getwox.com)) that I would like to open with this shortcut. If possible, I would like to rebind the opening of the start menu to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd>.

I imagine some registry hacking is required.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/987834/how-to-modify-windows-10-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

Here is the original [thread](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/).

You can map any key to any key in Windows 10. You have to use a utility called [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/).

Download and open the utility. Click the Add button to bring Add New Key Mapping dialog, here, you can either select the keys to map from the lists, or just click the Type Key button and press the key manually.

After setting press **Write to Registry** button then log off or reboot to take the changes effect.