# Prevent Ctrl+Alt+S from trying to open HP System Information

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, hp-pavilion

On my HP laptop, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in any program opens HP System Information, as well as doing the appropriate function in the active program. I use this combination a fair bit, so it's very annoying to have to keep closing this pop-up window.

There is a proper fix, but it's only for Windows Vista and 7.

The solution given on the HP forums for Windows 8 & 10 is to delete/rename the pop-up program's `.exe` file. However, if an HP update is run on the computer, the program is restored. Other solutions work for Windows earlier than 8, e.g. searching for the shortcut and deleting the shortcut key. I'm wondering if there's a permanent solution, e.g. editing a hidden shortcut or the Windows registry?

Comment: "I use this combination a fair bit" – so do Polish users. Interesting story: [*The curious case of the disappearing Polish S*](https://medium.engineering/the-curious-case-of-disappearing-polish-s-fa398313d4df).

Answer (score 1):

Option 1(delete HPSysInfo.exe):

1. Delete "C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\HP Hotkey Support\HPSysInfo.exe"
2. Try ctrl+alt+s, a window will pop up asking if you want to remove "ctrl+alt+s" shortcut key, just click yes.

Option 2(avoid deleting HPSysInfo.exe):

1. 7-Zip HPSysInfo.exe to a place of  you choice, and delete the original HPSysInfo.exe
2. Try ctrl+alt+s, a window will pop up asking if you want to remove "ctrl+alt+s" shortcut key, just click yes.
3. Now you can either unzip HPSysInfo.exe and copy it back to its original directory or do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Very annoying!

The thing is that the shortcut to the HPSysInfo lives in Windows Start Menu, and its configuration includes a shortcut key.

Basically you can just

1. Search for "HP System Information" item in the start menu.
2. Do "Open File Location" over this item (right mouse button click).
3. Get Properties of the shortcut.
4. Remove Shortcut Key by pressing Del or Backspace and save that shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

- Nirsoft's [ShortcutsMan](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shman.html) can display and disable some keyboard shortcuts, though not those built into the OS. It depends on how HP has hooked into message handling.
- Use a third-party tool such as [AutoHotkey](https://superuser.com/questions/987834/how-to-modify-windows-10-keyboard-shortcuts) to intercept the key before HP gets it.
- Write a short batch file to rename HP's executable. It lessens the nuisance of doing it manually for each update. *sigh*

Comment: The AutoHotkey idea wouldn't work. AHK can direct a key combination to a single program, so if it was capable of blocking HP, it would only work in one program.You would also have to map it to the correct function rather than letting the program handle the key combination itself.

Comment: ShortcutsMan shows only one shortcut with a hotkey, and unfortunately it's not Ctrl+Alt+S, so maybe HP has hooked directly into Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop it from starting when the computer starts.

You can use the program AutoRuns (for example).

The program is probably called:

HPMessageService HP Message Service HP Inc.

and it is located at:

C:\program files (x86)\hp\hp system event\hpmsgsvc.exe

It is also possible that it is:

C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\HP Hotkey Support\HPSysInfo.exe

You can also delete or rename the program and it won't start anymore.

Comment: Renaming `"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\HP System Event\SysInfoEx.exe"` works without disabling the service for the rest of the laptop keys